# What the right expression for "pursue a requirement"?

Tags: verbs, expressions, vocabulary

I have the following sentence in my essay.

"We pursue a unique requirement, that is, how to optimally utilize the space for.......".

I feel like "pursue a requirement" is a little odd. 
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

- "We have an ultimate goal, that is, learn how to..."
- "We're after a most peculiar objective..."
- "Our target is to optimally utilize the space for..."

Excuse me, prescriptivists, for the split infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

From an engineering perspective, one does not pursue a requirement. The team implements the requirement. Or, the design satisfies the requirement. One pursues a goal or objective (or a dream).

Also, are you stating a future state in you are in the process of achieving the "optimally utilize..."? Or do you have a solution that you want to sell?

Just the small change "We pursue a unique goal..." may help clarify your statement.

What do you want to emphasize: that your pursuit is unique: no one has ever "...optimally utilized space for something"? Or is your *design* or *approach* unique to a common problem of "optimally utilize the space"? Depending on the emphasize you could say:

"We will optimally utilize the space for ..." 
"Our design optimally utilizes the space for ..."
"Our unique design optimizes the space for ..."